# Pass data from flask python to HTML form

Tags: python, html, flask, get, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to pass a value to a HTML form through `GET` request the same way you can do it with WTForms. I want to pre-populate the form fields with some text. When the user edits the values and clicks submit, the new values will be posted and updated in the database. Should I use `GET` request to do that? Below is a sample of what I'm trying to do

```
 @app.route("/myroute", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def myroute():
if request.method == 'GET':
    request.form['field1'] = 'some text'
    request.form['fields'] = 'some text'
```

edit:
this is how its done with WTForms

```
form = SomeForm()

if request.method == 'GET':

    form.field1.data = 'some text'
    form.field2.data = 'some text'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass data to html page using flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669102/how-to-pass-data-to-html-page-using-flask)

Comment: thankyou for the response. is this the best way to do it? i want to get it right cause you can do the same with WTForms. ive updated the question to show you.

Comment: Is this possible? Much appreciated.

Comment: Ok. I'm not getting anything else. I might as well end it there. Thanks