# python file pass value to html with flask face Internal Server Error (jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html)

Tags: python, flask, post

python file pass value to html with flask

- error

> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.`

```
import mysql.connector
# from mysql import connector
import webbrowser
import time
import pymysql
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="196.168.101.141",
  user="root",
  password="password123", 
  database="cool_db",  
  auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
              
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_DESC  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = 'en_1-01'")                       
                                         
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

print(myresult)    # does get the result I want 

# but below function not send "myresult" to html successfully
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", myresult = myresult)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

- index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <p> this is {{myresult}}</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

I already read through the discussion [how to pass data to html page using flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669102/how-to-pass-data-to-html-page-using-flask) and also other tutorial but not see how to solve, therefore I need a hand thanks

error:`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html`
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you change the last line of your python code from `app.run()` to `app.run(debug=True)`? It will show the actual error instead of just saying 'Internal Server Error'. I believe we would be able to help you out better if we know what the actual error is.

Comment: the [youtube tutorial ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDOSQAq8cls) I follow, to pass python value to html

Comment: Just change the last line of the code and run the code, you will be able to see detailed error on the webpage instead of just 'Internal Server Error'.

Comment: I just update, the error is `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html` with screenshot in post

Comment: I hope my answer helped you in resolving your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is no index.html file present in the templates folder. In flask, you need to create a folder named `templates` in the same location where your app.py file is located. Inside that templates folder, you need to create the `index.html` file.

So, your directory structure should look like:

```
|- firstflaskapp.py
|- templates/
|   |- index.html
```

I am sure this will resolve your error.

The full directory structure followed used in flask is:

```
|- app.py
|- templates/
|   |- index.html
|   |- login.html
|   |- ...
|- static/
|   |- css/
|   |   |- main.css
|   |- images/
|   |   |- logo.png
|   |- ...
|- requirements.txt
```

- `app.py` is the main Flask application file
- `templates/` directory contains HTML templates for the application
- `static/` directory contains static files like CSS, JS, images, etc.
- `requirements.txt` is a text file containing the list of python libraries by the application.

Answer (score 1):

```
import mysql.connector
import webbrowser
import time
import pymysql
from flask import Flask,render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="196.168.101.141",
  user="root",
  password="password123", 
  database="cool_db",  
  auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)    
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# send result to index.html
@app.route('/')
def index():
    mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_PRICE  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = '%s'",(request.args.get("ProductID"),))
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    return render_template("Myshop.html", myresult = myresult)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: still get error though, I post the screen shot here, https://imgur.com/a/5xR7eW7

Comment: Change:
mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_PRICE  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = '%s'",(request.args.get("ProductID"),))
 to:
mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_PRICE  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = %s",(request.args.get("ProductID"),))

I removed the quotes around %s

Answer (score 1):

you dont enter the Myshop.html in the url if your using flask. You go to the `/` route and it will render the Myshop.html.

If you want to pass data from the get request like in your example

```
http://192.168.0.206:8080/?ProductID=001
```

You can access that data via the request

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # if key doesn't exist, returns None
    myresult = request.args.get('ProductID')

    return render_template("Myshop.html", myresult = myresult)
```

This tutorial explains it in more detail: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask

Comment: humm, my question is **Question: how to trigger .py script by inputing the url like `http://192.168.0.206:8080/english/MyShop.html?ProductID=001`** , that anyone can type the url `http://......ProductID=001` ,  `http://.......ProductID=007` to load the new page; seems for now, we still need to execute pyscript which is middle step of the  "task order in pic", I want the flow is from first step to the last step

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? This isn't a full working example. To make it functional you should place the database query in a seperate function. And call that function with the ProductID data you take out of the request. So something like `myresult = my_db_query(request.args.get('ProductID'))` where `my_db_query()` is this new function